# Background image transition using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a little jQuery code that changes the background image in the box.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-wrapper" id="box">
    <div class="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQUERY**

```
     slide=Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1); slide=(slide==0?1:slide);
        $("#box").attr("style", "background-image:url(images/slider/"+(slide)+".jpg);");
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#box").attr("style", "background-image:url(images/slider/"+(slide)+".jpg);");
            slide++; if(slide>6) slide=1;
        }, 6000
);
```

**CSS**

```
.content-wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding:0px !important;
    height:600px;
}
.content-wrapper > .content{
    width:100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#box {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
#box > .content{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#FFF;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CreativForm/yjq6opLv/)**

My idea is when page is loaded each time show random pictures and start slide that changes image every 6 seconds. All this works nicely, but I do not know how to make a nice transition. fadeIn() or fadeOut() is out of the question because over the images I have fixed text content. I do not want to use too large libraries for background slider, so I'm interested in the simplest solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: so you want us to decide for you which transition you should make? That' a visual design question. A fadein/fadeout with text over image could work using some sort of background layer between the text and the images, such as a drop-shadow, a colored rectangle, ensuring enough contrast and legibility, whatever the text, whatever the image.

Comment: it's nice to paste your code on fiddle

Comment: Good idea @ManProgrammer [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CreativForm/yjq6opLv/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so if you want to slide left and right [Fiddle:Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aps9mozd/):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 3000,
        fade = 1000;
    var banners = $('.banner');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;
    setTimeout(cycle, delay);

    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i % len]).hide("slide", function(){
             $(banners[++i % len]).show("slide", {
                direction: "left"
            });
            setTimeout(cycle, delay);
        });
    }
});
```

if you want to slide up and down : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47cggt7r/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 3000, fade = 1000;
    var banners = $('.banner');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;

    setTimeout(cycle, delay);

    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i%len]).slideUp(fade, function() {
            $(banners[++i%len]).slideDown(fade, function() {
                setTimeout(cycle, delay);   
            });
        });
    }

});
```

you can try to combine those to come up with a nice transition.

Comment: This is phenomenal but not entirely what I was looking for. Look [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CreativForm/yjq6opLv/). You change the entire DIV and content. I need to somehow make a slide in the background to be some kind of effect or transition. But this is a good basis for me to try something. Thanks!